# Which method would more accurately help to identify the unknown concentration of a protein sample between the A280 and the Bradford methods?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protein-expression

I quantified my protein using the standard Bradford method and the A280 methods and obtained values that were far off from the theoretical value of the protein of interest, and therefore was wondering if one method is better to use than the other.

Comment: Did both assays agree though?

Comment: Hi Sara I Have a nice guide method for you. In this time I cant send it to you because...' I will send it to you soon

Comment: Is the Bradford result much higher than the one for the A280?

Comment: Bradford is better and better than that is BCA. A280 relies on the presence of tryptophan which is not necessarily present in all proteins in same numbers.

Comment: @WYSIWYG For A280, shouldn't the tryptophan (and tyrosine and cystine) be accounted for in the extinction coefficient? Bradford/BCA is also dependent on amino acid content and is relative to a standard. If the unknown and standard proteins have a wildly different Arg/hydrophobic content, the results won't be very accurate.

Comment: I suppose the AA content will be important for A280 if it's being done relative to a standard as opposed to using the extinction coefficient.

Comment: Make sure the buffer your sample is in is compatible with the assay you're using, and that is is free of detergents, etc., as they can skew both assays. There are detergent-compatible assays available, check Pierce. I agree with @WYSIWYG that BCA is superior to the two you're currently using, just make sure you're using an appropriate standard. For example, if you're measuring IgG, don't use BSA as the standard.

Comment: I suppose SDS-PAGE could be another approach to estimate a concentration, but mostly to make sure you protein solution has protein.

Comment: Chris- Both methods were equally far apart from the literature value. And thank you everyone else for your input.

Comment: @canadianer tryptophan quenches the fluorescence of tyrosine and phenylalanine afaik. Moreover 280 is the absorption maxima for trp; others absorb shorter wavelengths.